# UITableView cell borders bleed through

Tags: ios, uitableview, background-color

I have two groups of cells, we'll call them header cells and body cells. I will always have 4 or less header cells, and 1 or more body cells. The header cells have a colored background (all the same background) and the body cells are all white. The problem is that when I scroll the tableView background color "bleeds through" between cells. **This is not a cell divider.** The image I attached shows what happens when I set the color to the green that's in the header.

I tried using clearColor for the background, but that shows a black line between all cells, which is not good. So far, we've just given the tableView a white background, since the majority of the cells are white it would be less noticible.

I also tried setting the tableView background color in the cellForRow, depending on the section, but that just causes it to switch what color is popping up, as I thought it would.

How can I get rid of the line that come through when scrolling when the cell background color is different than the tableView background color?

[image: Example of cell borders.]

Comment: did u try  [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Did you see the bold text that specified that that's not what those are?

Comment: how do you know that is not a separator ?

Comment: I turned them off. That's also not what they look like. Separators are not the full width, and are thicker.

Comment: you shouldnt hide the separator. You shold give it a color that matches the table cell!

Comment: this could help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637057/1-pixel-gap-between-first-and-second-cell-in-grouped-uitableview

Comment: @CodyHarness did you tried to to hide cell footer ?

Comment: @KishoreKumar Never implemented them.

Comment: @CodyHarness if you do that then your cell bottom line problem will solve